# Non-isomorphic direct products of a solvable and a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a solvable Lie algebra $\frak{a}$ and a semisimple Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ we can take their semidirect product $\frak{a} \rtimes \frak{g}$, with respect to a Lie algebra map $\frak{g} \to \mathrm{Der}(\frak{a})$. For the zero map $\frak{g} \to \mathrm{Der}(\frak{a})$ we get the usual direct product. But can there exist more than one non-zero map $\frak{g} \to \frak{a}$, giving two non-isomorphic semi-direct product? What is a motivating example? I will be interested most in a example in the context of Levi's theorem.

Comment: Yes of course. If $\mathfrak{a}$ is abelian of dimension $n$, there are as many types as $n$-dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ over the given field (well, modulo automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$). For instance for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, there are as many as partitions of $n$.

Comment: What if $\frak{a}$ is non-abelian?

Comment: In general is $\mathfrak{s}$ is a semisimple Levi factor in $\mathrm{Der}(\mathfrak{a})$, things should be essentially governed by homomorphisms $\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{s}$.

Comment: @YCor: this is what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be the ground field of characteristic zero.

For $n\ge 1$, let $\mathfrak{v}_n$ denote an $n$-dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$ over $K$ ($(n-1)$-th symmetric power of the standard 2-dimensional representation). Then $\mathfrak{v}_3\rtimes\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$ and ($\mathfrak{v}_1\oplus\mathfrak{v}_2)\rtimes\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$ are non-direct semidirect products and are not isomorphic (the first is perfect and not the second).

Note: however, in general (say over the complex or real numbers), there are only finitely many homomorphisms from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\mathrm{Der}(\mathfrak{a})$ up to conjugacy, and hence there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of semidirect products.